# How do I get the average of an array with the press of a button?

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I have problems with some coding regarding a grade calculator. I have looked around everywhere but I can't figure it out. It comes out with NaN.

```
var inputText;
var kArry = [];
var avg;
var antal;
var sum;

function karakter(){
    var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value; 
    if (inputText == 12 || inputText == 10 || inputText == 7 || 
        inputText == 4 || inputText == 2 || inputText == 0 || inputText == -3) {
        if(inputText !== "") {
            kArry.push(inputText); 
            };
        }
    document.getElementById("arrayText").innerHTML = kArry; 
    antal += 1;
    sum += inputText;
}

function gennemsnit() { 
    avg = sum/antal;
    document.getElementById("gennemsnit").innerHTML = Math.round(avg); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What goes wrong:

- `sum` has no initial value. The actual value is `undefined` and if you add a (numerical) value, you get a string with `'undefined'` at the start of the string.

  Later by using a divsion with the count, this value yields [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).
- Same goes for `antal`, where it is declared, but not initialized with zero.
- Using a string, instead of a number for adding to `sum`. There you could take a [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), which converts a stringed number to a number.
- Assuming the values are the allowed values, you could check the input and push this value to the array, directly without need of another check for emptyness of the input string.

Together:

```
function karakter() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;

  if (inputText == 12 || inputText == 10 || inputText == 7 || inputText == 4 || inputText == 2 || inputText == 0 || inputText == -3) {
    kArry.push(inputText);
    document.getElementById("arrayText").innerHTML = kArry;
    antal += 1;
    sum += +inputText;
  }
}


function gennemsnit() {
  var avg = sum / antal;
  document.getElementById("gennemsnit").innerHTML = Math.round(avg);
}

var kArry = [];
var antal = 0;
var sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the average on the spot by getting the sum of all the elements and then dividing it by the size of the array.

```js
var list = [12, 10, 7, 4, 2, 0, -3];

document.querySelector("#calc").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var average = list.reduce(function(sum, item) {
    return sum + item;
  }, 0) / list.length;
  console.log(average);
});
```

```html
<button id="calc">Get Average</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add strings, numbers, and undefined to each other.
So start the numbers at 0 and parse the strings into numbers.

```
var inputText;
var kArry = [];
var avg;
var antal = 0; // Start as zero.
var sum = 0; // Start as zero.


function karakter(){

    var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value; 
    if (inputText == 12 || inputText == 10 || inputText == 7 || 
        inputText == 4 || inputText == 2 || inputText == 0 || inputText == -3) {
            if(inputText !== "") {
            kArry.push(inputText); 
            };
        }
    document.getElementById("arrayText").innerHTML = kArry; 
    antal += 1;
    sum += parseInt( inputText, 10 ); // We want the value as a number
}


function gennemsnit() { 
        avg = sum/antal;
        document.getElementById("gennemsnit").innerHTML = Math.round(avg); 
}
```